# sp_executesql bug?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why I get error when call my stored procedure using sp_executesql?

Doesn't works.

```
exec sp_executesql N'sp_clnt_regional_experts_territories',
                   N'@action nvarchar(3), @regional_expert_id int,@region_id int,@territory_id int',
                   @action = N'SEL',
                   @regional_expert_id = 2,
                   @region_id = -1,
                   @territory_id = -1
```

> Procedure or function 'sp_clnt_regional_experts_territories' expects
>   parameter '@action', which was not supplied.

Works fine:

```
EXEC sp_clnt_regional_experts_territories                   
     @action = N'SEL',
     @regional_expert_id = 2,
     @region_id = -1,
     @territory_id = -1
```

Where the stored proc is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_clnt_regional_experts_territories]
    @action NVARCHAR(3),
    @regional_expert_id INT = -1,
    @region_id INT = -1,
    @territory_id INT = -1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your sp_executesql is wrong .You need to format it like the one below

```
 DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
 DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
 DECLARE @action nvarchar(3)
 DECLARE @regional_expert_id int
 DECLARE @region_id int
 DECLARE @territory_id INT
 Set @SQLString=N'EXEC sp_clnt_regional_experts_territories @action,
                                             @regional_expert_id ,@region_id   ,@territory_id'

 Set @ParmDefinition='@action NVARCHAR(3),
            @regional_expert_id INT ,
            @region_id INT ,
            @territory_id INT '

EXECUTE sp_executesql
@SQLString,
@ParmDefinition,
@action=N'SEL',
@regional_expert_id=2,
@region_id=-1,
@territory_id=-1
```

Instead of directly entering everything in one statement ,dissecting your code into different parts helps you find your problems easily .

Comment: Thats fine .Your sql profiler wont dissect these codes for the user . I actually meant that you should be writing the code in the above manner which helps in a better readability . Anyway you didn't pass the parameters right

Comment: @user1455361 - If SQL Profiler was showing you that statement then make sure your application is setting `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` not `Text`

Answer (score 1):

the error is because you didn't include the parameters right after your stored procedure name, which is required by sp_executesql

```
exec sp_executesql N'sp_clnt_regional_experts_territories @action,@regional_expert_id ,@region_id   ,@territory_id',
                   N'@action nvarchar(3), @regional_expert_id int,@region_id int,@territory_id int',
                   @action = N'SEL',
                   @regional_expert_id = 2,
                   @region_id = -1,
                   @territory_id = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) says of `@params`:

> Is one string that contains the definitions of all parameters that have **been embedded in @stmt**.

(Emphasis added)

So, any parameters you identify there must also be mentioned in `@stmt`, as the other answers have pointed out.